# Prevent checking checkboxes in second row if already checked in first row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of 5 checkboxes that are displayed in a row. Then, on a second row, I have the same number of 5 checkboxes. Then on a third row, I have the same number of 5 checkboxes.

What I want to achieve is, that if I have checked the first three checkboxes in the first row, then I should not be able to check the first three checboxes in the second row. I should only be able to check the last two checkboxes in the second row. How can I achieve this validation based on the subsequent rows of checkboxes in jquery ?

The first row of the five checkboxes are as follows:

```
 <div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3" disabled>
            <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
            <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
            <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-3">
            <label for="car-4-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-3">
            <label for="car-5-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

The second row of the five checkboxes:

```
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-4" disabled>
                <label for="car-1-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-4">
                <label for="car-2-4"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-4">
                <label for="car-3-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-4">
                <label for="car-4-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-4">
                <label for="car-5-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

The third row of the five checkboxes:

```
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-5" disabled>
                <label for="car-1-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-5">
                <label for="car-2-5"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-5">
                <label for="car-3-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-5">
                <label for="car-4-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-5">
                <label for="car-5-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

Comment: How do you name the rest of your checkboxes? You might wanna just add the 3 rows

Comment: @Eddie : Please check my edited question

Comment: So users can only click one checkbox per column?

Comment: Yes exactly. If the above column is selected, the user should not be able to select the below column.

Comment: Why not just use radios buttons instead with same name in a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method if you don't want the checkboxes to be disabled when selecting one:
(That kind of works like a radio button, but with the `id`s, not the `name`)

```js
$(".cars-item input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var box = $(this); // Checkbox just clicked
  if (box.is(":checked")) { // If the checkbox was just checked
    var box_id = $(this).attr('id'); // Get its id
    var boxes_ids = box_id.substr(0, (box_id.length - 1)); // Remove last number to make a generic id

    // Find checkboxes corresponding to generic id and uncheck them (except the one we checked)
    $(".cars-item input:checkbox[id^='" + boxes_ids + "']").not(box).prop("checked", false)
  }

  // Here are the values of the selected checkboxes.
  // I don't know which form you want, I've used an array
  var checkeds = [];
  $(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
});
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-3">
      <label for="car-4-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-3">
      <label for="car-5-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-4">
      <label for="car-1-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-4">
      <label for="car-2-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-4">
      <label for="car-3-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-4">
      <label for="car-4-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-4">
      <label for="car-5-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-5">
      <label for="car-1-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-5">
      <label for="car-2-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-5">
      <label for="car-3-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-5">
      <label for="car-4-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-5">
      <label for="car-5-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I want to obtained the value of selected checkboxes ?

Comment: @ExpertGenie What are the values, for you ? Is it the `id`s ?

Comment: Yes @Takit Isy. The values. because I will save the selected checkboxes in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```js
//Add event listener on checkbox inside js-cars-item 
$('.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();      //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked");             //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this;                               //Checkbox object

  $('.js-cars-item').each(function() {         //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("disabled", chk);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-3">
      <label for="car-4-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-3">
      <label for="car-5-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-4">
      <label for="car-1-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-4">
      <label for="car-2-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-4">
      <label for="car-3-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-4">
      <label for="car-4-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-4">
      <label for="car-5-4"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-5">
      <label for="car-1-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-5">
      <label for="car-2-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-5">
      <label for="car-3-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-4-5">
      <label for="car-4-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-5-5">
      <label for="car-5-5"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Eddie. :) You should use the html structure of the OP, as it will change some of your JS code.

Comment: The JS code will still work with OP's HTML. No need to change on the JS

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Already tried. I'm commenting you to not "make a better answer", because I know you dislike.

Comment: I've suggested an edit for your post. I like your use of the .index() method, I often forget that.

Comment: Ohh yeah you are right. Thanks. Your code works too. +1 :)